# How do you map-replace characters in Javascript similar to the 'tr' function in Perl?

Tags: javascript, perl, character-encoding, transliteration

I've been trying to figure out how to map a set of characters in a string to another set similar to the `tr` function in Perl.

I found [this site that shows equivalent functions in JS and Perl](http://www.lemoda.net/perl/perl-js/perl-js.html), but sadly no tr equivalent.

the `tr` (transliteration) function in Perl maps characters one to one, so

```
     data =~ tr|\-_|+/|;
```

would map

```
     - => + and _ => /
```

How can this be done efficiently in JavaScript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace multiple characters in one replace call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576983/replace-multiple-characters-in-one-replace-call)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

There isn't a built-in equivalent, but you can get close to one with [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
data = data.replace(/[\-_]/g, function (m) {
    return {
        '-': '+',
        '_': '/'
    }[m];
});
```

Comment: very nice with the callback function, what does return{..}[m] do?

Comment: @qodeninja The object (`{...}`) defines the character mapping, with expected matches as keys/properties and replacements as values. The current match, `m`, is then used lookup its own replacement (`[m]`) from the object, which is returned back to `replace` to perform the actual replacement.

Comment: Apparently the answer is "yes," but not as succinctly as Perl.

Comment: When we have an array `arr` full of such substitutions, and the matches follow a simple pattern that can be given completely by a regex, it's nice to have a default in case the regex was a little to general and matched something that wasn't in `arr`.  In that case, the function body should be `return arr[m] || m;` to just return the match itself without any substitution (rather than `undefined`).

Comment: Not sure about the performance of this, but defining the object ("dictionary") as a global variable may be faster (avoid recreate each time).

Comment: @user202729 Is it really recreated? This should be easily optimized by the runtime, if that is even necessary - that structure is part of the function's code and not a variable.

Comment: @Mörre The cached version appears to be 2-3% faster for short string: https://jsben.ch/NKx3z

Comment: If you only have a few, consider chaining `data.replace("a","A").replace("b","B")`

Answer (score 8):

Method:

```
String.prototype.mapReplace = function(map) {
    var regex = [];
    for(var key in map)
        regex.push(key.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&"));
    return this.replace(new RegExp(regex.join('|'),"g"),function(word){
        return map[word];
    });
};
```

A perfect example:

```
var s = "I think Peak rocks!"
s.mapReplace({"I think":"Actually","rocks":"sucks"})
// console: "Actually Peak sucks!"
```

Comment: @qodeninja It's the same technique, while this method allows to use a dynamic JSON kv mapping. It might be slower than the answer, because it generates the Regex and replacement dictionary for you. So use this method while you need dynamic replacement, use the answer if you only need to handle static wordset.

Answer (score 7):

I can't vouch for 'efficient' but this uses a regex and a callback to provide the replacement character.

```js
function tr( text, search, replace ) {
    // Make the search string a regex.
    var regex = RegExp( '[' + search + ']', 'g' );
    var t = text.replace( regex, 
            function( chr ) {
                // Get the position of the found character in the search string.
                var ind = search.indexOf( chr );
                // Get the corresponding character from the replace string.
                var r = replace.charAt( ind );
                return r;
            } );
    return t;
}
```

For long strings of search and replacement characters, it might be worth putting them in a hash and have the function return from that. ie, tr/abcd/QRST/ becomes the hash { a: Q, b: R, c: S, d: T } and the callback returns hash[ chr ].

Comment: +1, even though: Doesn't support "]", "\" and "^". Doesn't support ranges. Doesn't support "\" escapes.

Comment: @ikegami see my attempt at beefing this function up here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192385/attempt-at-perl-transliteration-function-in-javascript-with-flags

Answer (score 3):

This functions, which are similar how it's built in Perl.

```js
function s(a, b){ $_ = $_.replace(a, b); }
function tr(a, b){ [...a].map((c, i) => s(new RegExp(c, "g"), b[i])); }

$_ = "Εμπεδοκλης ο Ακραγαντινος";

tr("ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΩ", "ABGDEZITIKLMNOPRSTIFHO");
tr("αβγδεζηθικλμνοπρστυφχω", "abgdezitiklmnoprstifho");
s(/Ξ/g, "X"); s(/Ψ/g, "Ps");
s(/ξ/g, "x"); s(/ψ/g, "Ps");
s(/ς/g, "s");

console.log($_);
```

Comment: Seems the best answer... But please explain better what is `s()`  and how to use `tr()`.  The ideal is only one  function `tr(x,from,to)`.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
var data = data.replace(/[-_]/g, (match) => {
    return  '+/'['-_'.indexOf(match)];
});
```

A function in the 2nd parameter of Replace will be invoked for every match of regex in the first parameter and its return value is used as the replacement text.

Answer (score 1):

This will map all `a`s to `b` and all `y` to `z`

```
var map = { a: 'b', y: 'z' };
var str = 'ayayay';

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    str[i] = map[str[i]] || str[i];
```

EDIT:

Apparently you can't do that with strings. Here's an alternative:

```
var map = { a: 'b', y: 'z' };
var str = 'ayayay', str2 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    str2.push( map[str[i]] || str[i] );
str2.join('');
```

Comment: Why post an answer without testing it and why leave the non-working answer in place after editing it?

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, one can also write

```
tr{-_}{+/}
```

as

```
my %trans = (
   '-' => '+',
   '_' => '/',
);

my $class = join '', map quotemeta, keys(%trans);
my $re = qr/[$class]/;

s/($re)/$trans{$1}/g;
```

This latter version can surely be implemented in JS without much trouble.

(My version lacks the duplication of Jonathan Lonowski's solution.)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted a function that allows passing a custom map object, so I wrote one based on [Jonathan Lonowski](http://Jonathan%20Lonowski)'s answer. If you are trying to replace special characters (the kind that need to be escaped in regular expressions) you'll have to do some more work.

```
const mapReplace = (str, map) => {
  const matchStr = Object.keys(map).join('|');
  if (!matchStr) return str;
  const regexp = new RegExp(matchStr, 'g');
  return str.replace(regexp, match => map[match]);
};
```

And it's used like this:

```
const map = { a: 'A', b: 'B', d: 'D' };
mapReplace('abcde_edcba', map);
// ABcDe_eDcBA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that receives text orig dest and replaces in text each character for the one in the corresponding position in dest.

Is is not good enough for cases where more than one character must be replaced by only one or vice-versa. It is not good enough for removing accents from Portuguese texts, which is my use case.

```
function tr(text, orig, dest) {
    console.assert(orig.length == dest.length);
    const a = orig.split('').map(i=> new RegExp(i, 'g'));
    const b = dest.split('');
    return a.reduce((prev, curr, idx) => prev.replace(a[idx], b[idx]), text );
}
```

How to use it:

```
var port  = "ÀÂÃÁÉÊÍÓÔÕÜÚÇáàãâêéíóõôúüç";
var ascii = "AAAAEEIOOOUUCaaaaeeiooouuc";
console.log(tr("não têm ações em seqüência", port, ascii)) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Similiar to Jonathan Lonowski answer but with words support, not just single tr chars

```
"aaabbccddeeDDDffd".replace( /(a|cc|DDD|dd)/g, m => ({'a':'B', 'cc':'DDD', 'DDD':'ZZZ', dd:'QQ'}[m]) ) 
// RESULT: "BBBbbDDDQQeeZZZffd"
```

Answer (score 1):

With only one map:

```js
const map = {
    '-': '+',
    '_': '/'
};

data = Object.entries(map).reduce((prev, entry) => prev.replace(...entry), data);
```