# A "translate" function in javascript like that in php?

Tags: javascript

Yes, I want a character "translate" function in javascript like that in php.
I made the following, but it is ghastly.  Surely there must be a better way -- using regular expressions?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function() { 
  "use strict";
  console.log(translate("abcdefg", "bdf", "XYZ")); // gives aXcYeZg -=-=-
}
function translate(v1, xlatfrom, xlatto) {
  var ch, ipos, retstr = "";
  if (xlatfrom.length != xlatto.length) return ""; // lengths must be =
  for (var i1=0; i1<v1.length; i1+=1) { // go through string
    ch = v1.substring(i1, i1+1); // character by character
    ipos = xlatfrom.indexOf(ch); // ck if in xlatfrom
    if (ipos >= 0) ch = xlatto.substring(ipos, ipos+1); // if yes, replace
    retstr += ch; } // build up return string
  return retstr;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: I've accepted the @dani-sc answer.  I'm not going to pursue performance.  But it's so DIDACTIC!  And thanks for the "spread operator" info.  Here's how I might use his answer:

```
function translate(v1, xlatfrom, xlatto) { // like the PHP translate
 var mapobj = strsToObject(xlatfrom, xlatto); // make str1.ch's:str2ch's object
 return [...v1].map(ch => mapobj[ch] || ch).join(''); // ... is js "spread operator"
}
function strsToObject(str1, str2) { // make object from strings
  if (str1.length != str2.length) return {}; // lengths must be =
  var retobj = {};
  for (var i1=0; i1<str1.length; i1+=1) { // just str[i1]: str2[i1]
    retobj[str1.substring(i1, i1+1)] = str2.substring(i1, i1+1); }
  return retobj;
}
```

or (this is GREAT! THANKS!)

```
function translate(v1, xlatfrom, xlatto) { // like the PHP translate
  if (xlatfrom.length != xlatto.length) return ""; // lengths must be =
  var mapobj = {}; // make object for mapping
  for (var i1=0; i1<xlatfrom.length; i1+=1) { // just str[i1]: str2[i1]
    mapobj[xlatfrom.substring(i1, i1+1)] = xlatto.substring(i1, i1+1); }
  return [...v1].map(ch => mapobj[ch] || ch).join(''); // ... is js "spread operator"
}
```

Comment: Something like the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10726638/1810460) might be what you're looking for

Comment: @Hamms Thanks, my searches didn't hit "Perl tr function".  Lots in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you want, you could use regular expressions like this:

```js
function translate(input, oldCharacters, newCharacters) {
  let output = input;
  const oldChArr = [...oldCharacters];
  const newChArr = [...newCharacters];
  for (let i = 0; i < oldChArr.length; i += 1) {
    output = output.replace(new RegExp(oldChArr[i], 'g'), newChArr[i]);
  }
  return output;
}

function translateFixed(input, replacements) {
  return input.replace(/./g, ch => replacements[ch] || ch);
}

function translateFixedNoRegEx(input, replacements) {
  return [...input].map(ch => replacements[ch] || ch).join('');
}

console.log(translate("abcdefgbdb", "bdf", "XYZ"));
console.log(translate("abcdefg", "cde", "dec"));
console.log(translateFixed("abcdefg", {c: 'd', d: 'e', e: 'c'}));
console.log(translateFixedNoRegEx("abcdefg", {c: 'd', d: 'e', e: 'c'}));
```

If you would be okay with changing the method's signature, it could be made a bit more concise of course.

Edit: I've added two more methods which actually achieve what you're looking for. Just for reference, I left the original method `translate` in there as well.

`translateFixed` uses regular expressions to match every single character and replace it if it was specified in the `replacements` parameter.
`translateFixedNoRegex` just creates an array of characters out of the `input` string and iterates over them. If the character `ch` matches one in the `replacements` parameter, it's replaced, otherwise it's left unchanged. Afterwards, we'll convert it back to a string by concatenating the characters.

You asked about [...array]: It's the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), introduced with ES6. When used on a string, it just takes every character and puts it as a single entry into an array. That means, these both lines are equivalent:

```js
console.log([..."mystring"]);
console.log("mystring".split(''));
```

Comment: Please say something about the "..." in "[...oldCharacters]".  I'd like to know about this.  A problem with your function -- "translate("abcdefg", "cde", "dec")" gives "abcccfg" instead of "abdecfg", which is what I would want.  I'm going to look more at this.  Thanks.

Comment: @dcromley Hi, I've edited my answer with two new functions and an explanation on [...array]

Comment: @Bergi I've checked my routines and dani-sc 's and there is NO COLLUSION!

Answer (score -1):

```js
function translate(val, xlatfrom, xlatto) { // 
  if (xlatfrom.length !== xlatto.length) return "";
  
  Array.from(xlatfrom).forEach((key, index) =>  {
    val = val.replace(key, xlatto[index]);
  })
  return val;
}

console.log(translate("abcdefg", "bdf", "XYZ"));
```

Comment: This suffers from the (I think) same problem as from @dani-sc,   "translate("abcdefg", "cde", "dxx")" gives "abxdxfg" instead of "abdxxfg", which is what I would want. I'm going to look more at this. Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't work if the letters in `xlatfrom` and `xlatto` collide

Comment: @Bergi Complete specs for this function are not mentioned. So one option left for me to loop into php translate() code and convert into javascript. I don't have that much time :)