# Replacing Mandaic characters with Hebrew characters in specific HTML tags break links

Tags: javascript, html

Why does the given JavaScript code that replaces Mandaic characters with Hebrew characters in a webpage break all the links in the page? The code is as follows:

```js
function replaceMandaicCharacters() {
  const mandaicLetters = "\u{0840}\u{0841}\u{0842}\u{0843}\u{0844}\u{0845}\u{0846}\u{0847}\u{0848}\u{0849}\u{084A}\u{084B}\u{084C}\u{084D}\u{084E}\u{084F}\u{0850}\u{0851}\u{0852}\u{0853}\u{0854}\u{0855}";
  const hebrewLetters = "אבגדחוזהטיכלמנסעפצקרשת";
  const targetTags = ["b", "td"];

  // Replace Mandaic characters in specific HTML tags
  for (const tag of targetTags) {
    const elements = document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    for (const element of elements) {
      const originalText = element.textContent;
      const regex = new RegExp(`[${mandaicLetters}]`, "g");
      const newText = originalText.replace(regex, (match) => {
        const index = mandaicLetters.indexOf(match);
        return hebrewLetters.charAt(index);
      });
      if (newText !== originalText) {
        element.textContent = newText;
      }
    }
  }

  // Replace Mandaic characters in all text nodes on the webpage
  const textNodes = document.evaluate(
    "//text()",
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null
  );
  for (let i = 0; i < textNodes.snapshotLength; i++) {
    const textNode = textNodes.snapshotItem(i);
    const originalText = textNode.textContent;
    const regex = new RegExp(`[${mandaicLetters}]`, "g");
    const newText = originalText.replace(regex, (match) => {
      const index = mandaicLetters.indexOf(match);
      return hebrewLetters.charAt(index);
    });
    if (newText !== originalText) {
      textNode.textContent = newText;
    }
  }
}

// Call replaceMandaicCharacters() whenever the DOM is updated
const observer = new MutationObserver(replaceMandaicCharacters);
observer.observe(document, { subtree: true, childList: true });
```

When I apply this code to a webpage, it replaces the Mandaic characters with Hebrew characters, but it also cancels links in the page, at least on some pages like [this](https://cal.huc.edu/manget_a_chapter.php?file=74410&sub=001&cset=M). How can I fix this issue and prevent links from being canceled?

Some suggestions, such as replacing only texts and not `href`s, did not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`.textContent` considers all the text content in a node and its descendants, and [setting it removes the descendants](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#sect3).

You'll want to find the individual text nodes beneath each candidate node, and only do the character replacement on their `textContent`.

btw There are some more efficient ways to do the character substitution stuff, [there are a few ideas illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50223069/21146235).